# How to make each click (of a single button) make the content of a title change?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I wanted to do a single button which every single one of its clicks would show the same word but with different sizes, fonts, weights, etc.

Like, for example: I have the word "become", written normally with Helvetica font and a button bellow it. When I click the button, the word should change to "become" but in uppercase and bold. Then, I would click it again, and it would change to the word "become" but in lowercase and with a line through it, and so on...

In my HTML I have:

```
<div id="container2">
<h4 id="original">Become</h4>
</div>

<h2 id="button">Transform me!</h2>
```

In my CSS I have:

```
@font-face {
font-family: Helvetica;
src: url(Helvetica CE Regular.ttf);
}

h4{
font-family: helvetica;
margin:0 auto;
text-align:center;
width:350px;
margin-top: 7%;
}

#button{
font-family: helvetica;
font-size: 25px;
background-color: inherit;
width: 165px;
margin: 0 auto;
margin-top: 3.5%;
padding: 0.5%;
position: static;
}


#button:hover {
text-decoration: underline;
}

#original{
font-size: 90px;
font-weight: bold;
text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

In my Javescript I have this for now:

```
var botao
var original = document.getElementById('original');

botao = document.getElementById("button");

botao.onclick = function () {
original.style.cssText = 'font-style:oblique'; 'text-transform: lowercase';
}
```

I'm having trouble finding online an answer to solve this... I'm also not very confortable with java, for now at least... 
If someone could help me out I would be very grateful.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: recommend you set up a number of CSS Classes. Have those stored in an `array` and then cycle thru them onclick. Changing the element class name on each click. Make sense?

Comment: So are you expecting the `css` properties to toggle from one set of styles to a different set or change from more than two sets? You could toggle a `class` name but if you want to toggle from more than two preset properties then it will no doubt require a different approach.

Comment: Paul, yes, it does make sense. I just don't know if I'll succeed doing it, ahah. I'll try nonetheless.

Comment: But first, I need to create different css classes that contain the styles I want for each version of the word, right? And they'll only exist in the css file, right? According to what you've said, I assumed they would only be written on my css file and not being applied on my html. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using jQuery for doing this. It is friendlier to beginners.

You just need to include the jQuery CDN link in your page, and then you can use jQuery ($) functions. Using classes makes sense. See the code.

```js
    $('.transformer').click(function(){
      if ($(this).siblings('h4').hasClass('original')) {
        $(this).siblings('h4').addClass('uppercase-bold');
        $(this).siblings('h4').removeClass('original');
      }
      else if($(this).siblings('h4').hasClass('uppercase-bold')){
        $(this).siblings('h4').addClass('italic');
        $(this).siblings('h4').removeClass('uppercase-bold'); 
      }

      else if($(this).siblings('h4').hasClass('italic')){
        $(this).siblings('h4').addClass('original');
        $(this).siblings('h4').removeClass('italic'); 
      }    
    });
```

```css
    .wrapper {
    border: 1px solid blue;
    padding: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    }

    h4 {
    text-transform: lowercase;
    }

    .uppercase-bold {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: blue;
    }
    
    .italic {
    font-style: italic;
    color: red;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


    <div class="wrapper">
    <h4 class="original">Become</h4>
    <button class="transformer">transform me!</button>
    </div>

    <div class="wrapper">
    <h4 class="original">To be, or not to be?</h4>
    <button class="transformer">transform me!</button>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a working version of suggestion above.
Added font size change added, works fine.

```js
const classes = ["class1", "class2", "class3"];
var selectedIndex = 0;

document.getElementById("button").addEventListener("click", function(){
  if(++selectedIndex >= classes.length) selectedIndex = 0;
  document.getElementById("original").className = classes[selectedIndex];
});
```

```css
.class1 { 
  color: red;
  font-size: 1.25em;
}

.class2 {
  color: blue;
  font-size: 1.75em;
 }
 
 .class {
  color: green;
  font-size: 2.5em;
 }
```

```html
<div id="container2">
<h4 id="original" clasx="class1">Become</h4>
</div>

<h2 id="button">Transform me!</h2>
```

Comment: Add the styles and then class names to array as appropriate.

Comment: I see. Thank you so much fo your help! I'll try it right now.

Comment: It works pretty good, overall, thank you once again! I just noticed that although in some classes I have the font-size with different values, the word's size does not change for some reason.

Comment: Post the styles an I will test if you like.

Comment: Ok, thank you!
I've got this in my CSS now:
 
.class1 {
 font-size: 90px;
 font-weight: bold;
 text-transform: lowercase;
 letter-spacing: 25px;
}

.class2 {
 font-size: 5px;
 font-weight: Regular;
 }

 .class3 {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: thin;
 }

 .class4 {
   font-size: 90px;
   font-style:oblique;
   text-transform: lowercase;
 }

 .class5 {
  font-size: 125px;
   text-decoration: line-through;
   text-transform: uppercase;

 }

Comment: The weird thing is that the word I'm applying the java into changes from regular to oblique, but it doesn't change the font's size or from upper to lowercase, for example...

Comment: Take a look here for text transforms. https://love2dev.com/blog/css-text-transform/.